# How to get extent of multiple geometries?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2

I can query a geometry extent like this:

```
select ST_Extent(geom) from tableName;
```

But sometimes I am querying geometries more than one. I am getting 5 points that different locations. So I wanto to zoom my map that containing this 5 points extent. Is this possible?

```
select geom from tableName where category='airport';
```

This gives me 5 airport. and I want to zoom this 5 point extent.

Answer (score 4):

You could use St_Envelope on all your airports

[docs !](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Envelope.html)

*ST_Envelope — Returns a geometry representing the bounding box of the supplied geometry.*

Answer (score 4):

Just use ST_Extent for the sub-query that selects your airports. The only trick is that in PostgreSQL you must use an alias for the subquery. Look at "a" in the following example which gives the aggregated extent of the 5 first geometries of the table.

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Extent(a.geom)) from 
(select geom from tableName limit 5) as a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function over your data :

```
select distinct (ST_Extent(geom)  over ())::geometry box from tableName category='airport';
```

Also since you tagged openlayers take a look at [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) you might find it helpful